# image slider and a cycle plugin of jquery not working together

Tags: jquery, plugins

Here i am using a image slider and a cycle plugin of jquery. but only one of them working whose code is placed above . Where is the problem ? mY CODE OF HEAD CONTENT IS GIVEN BELOW.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/easySlider1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link href="css/jq.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/cycle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/chili-1.7.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#s1').cycle({
         fx: 'scrollDown',
         speedIn: 2000,
         speedOut: 500,
         easeIn: 'easeInCirc',
         easeOut: 'easeOutBounce',
         delay: -2000
     });

         $("#slider").easySlider({
             auto: true,
             continuous: true,
             nextId: "slider1next",
             prevId: "slider1prev"
         });



 });
```

```
<link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

slider code

```
    <div id="slider" >
        <ul>                
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/30"><img src="images/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/7"><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/25"><img src="images/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/26"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/27"><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>          
        </ul>

    </div>
     <div class="clear">
     </div>
 </div>
```

and cycle plugin html

```
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" alt="" />

        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" alt=""  />

        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" alt="" />

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you have a negative value for the cycle plugin's delay?

Comment: Put code of #slider and #s1 for example.

Comment: yeah..both code work fine saprately...but together only first one work...nd both code have been copied from somwhere so code is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include order may matter and you have a duplicate `jquery.js`. Try this order:

```
<link href="css/jq.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/cycle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="js/easySlider1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/chili-1.7.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Accept? Checkmark? Pleeeeeeease? :) Helps you too in the future.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. I should vote you up then :D The faqs say 15 is to vote up (arrow up). I believe you can click the checkmark outline. Try it :)

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr can u plz give a look at a link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895524/autocomplete-is-not-working-when-used-with-slider"